# Programmatically Creating Custom Functions in an Excel Add-in using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel, add-in, custom-functions-excel

I'm in the process of "translating" a Google Sheets add-on to an Excel add-in. I have trouble finding if and how custom functions would be programmatically created using JavaScript in an Excel add-in (which btw is really simple for Google Sheets).

Is this possible? If so, could you provide a basic example?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript custom functions in Excel are now available in Developer Preview for anyone to try building as part of an add-in: https://aka.ms/customfunctions

-Michael (PM for add-ins)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're after. In the new add-in model in Excel add-ins are basically web pages in a frame with a document object that you can manipulate and that refers to the worksheet. You can create any function provided the APIs available are sufficient.

Comment: Alright, that's probably a lack of research on my part then. For Google Sheets add-ons, you can just call your functions in cells by putting an '=' sign before like =functionName(arg1;arg2). I was wondering if there was the same mechanism that would allow the functions to be automatically called or if I have to watch the cells and parse the function name and the arguments if the cell started with an '=' sign.